# Simplifying repetitive search and replace tasks with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm currently editing a bunch of information for comicrack and need to format the text before I input it into comicrack.

Right now I'm just pasting the text into Notepad++ running two instances of search and replace then pasting that into comicrack.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this such as a script I can run each time.

---

**The search and replace instances I run are:**

1. > Find:                             (Just empty space)
   >
   > Replace with : -

   **and then**
2. > Find: \r\n
   >
   > Replace with: ;

   **in this order**

---

Is there a way to do this with a script or a way to assist in the repetitive task I use with Notepad++, or am I stuck doing it this way as I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Record and reuse a **macro** with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

> ### **Instructions**
>
> - **Create a Macro**
>
>   1. Get the data content / files opened in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
>   2. Select <kbd>**`Macro`**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**`Start Recording`**</kbd>
>   3. Perform the search and replace, etc. operation
>   4. Select <kbd>**`Macro`**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**`Stop Recording`**</kbd>
> - **Reusing Macro Options**
>
>   - **One Time Playback:** Select <kbd>**`Macro`**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**`Playback`**</kbd> or press
>       <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**`Shift`**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**`P`**</kbd>
>       to have the **macro** rerun the recorded operation(s) as many times as
>       you need.
>   - **Save for Future Playback:** Select <kbd>**`Macro`**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**`Save Current Recorded Macro...`**</kbd> and then from the
>       **Shortcut** window type in a **Name** to save it as.
>
>     <sup>You can optionally create a hotkey combination to press to run the saved Macro as needed.</sup>
>
>     [image]
>   - **Repetitive Playback:** Select <kbd>**`Macro`**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**`Run a Macro Multiple Times...`**</kbd> and then select the
>       **Macro to run**, the number of **times** to run it, or to run it **until the end of the file** .
>
>     [image]